# How do i $push to a object in an array in a mongoDB database with node?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, mongodb, express

I Want to push an object to an object inside an array on my MongoDB database. I'm trying to use $push submits[postDate] but it is giving me a red line under the first "[" . Any idea how to fix this?

My code:

```
        app.post('/add-submit', (req,res) => {

        let postDate = new Date();
        let dd = String(postDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        let mm = String(postDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        let yyyy = postDate.getFullYear();

        postDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

        subject = req.body.subject

        let pushValue = {
            time: req.body.time,
            description: req.body.description,
            date: postDate 
        }
            
        console.log(pushValue)

        console.log(postDate)

        let myquery = { username: req.body.username};
        let newvalues = { 
            $push : {
                submits[postDate] : {
                    [subject] : pushValue 
                }
            }                               
        }
        db.collection("users").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, (err, response) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 document updated");
            res.redirect('/users/'+req.body.id)
        });   
    })
```

But i get this error:

```
    D:\Users\willi\Documents\Node\StudyWebApp\server.js:186
                submits[postDate] : {
                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is what I want it to look like on the database:

[image: mongodb database]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear your object model but I think you need use `$` keyword.

To get the position in 'submits' you try `submit[postDate]` but there is no the right way, instead you need something like that:

```
db.collection.update({
  "username": "test",
  "submits.date": "16/10/2020"
},
{
  $push: {
    "submits.$.subjects": {
      "subjectName": {
        "time": "1234",
        "description": "desc"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I will try to explain hoy it works, it's pretty simple.

The first object is where you want to 'point'. Is like a 'find', the place where you want to do the second part (the push). So using `$` operator, you will work in that exact part of the document.

So, the second object (`$push` object) is the operation. Using `submits.$.subjects` the operation will be done at this particular section of document.

I have no tested it in Node but your code has `myquery` and `newvalues` variables so it should be the same and works.

By the way, I have replied the query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qv-mwBkYoR6)

Comment: I did what you said to do and got no errors but nothing showed up on the database. Should I already have the array and objects on the database for it to work or does it create them automatically?

Comment: It is necessary to exists, because the query update the element that match the first object (username and submits.date). So if no element is found, none will be updated.

Comment: how do i check if it doesn't exist and what do I do then?

Comment: Please tell me how I'm going to create it in the first place :) It doesn't magically get on the database I have no idea how to get it there in the first place. When I try it adds random objects in between the objects I want to add. How do I create a object on the database that i can then add to with the code you provided.

Comment: Please be patient. If you are using Node you have the option to use the methods ```insertOne()``` or ```insertMany()```. You can check the [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/insertOne)

Comment: I did exactly what you said to do but my database looks like this {"_id":{"$oid":"5f8b0f2c2089282c4cf2752f"},"username":"nt","email":"n@t","password":"$2b$10$y7GXHy0GXG4c6vNqGRDeY.ywBkWRNl0Q7KfO1yAGBh2M1OgeaIRAu","submits":[{"date":"16/10/2020","subjects":[{"subject1":{"time":"15","description":"desc"}}]}]} and i get this error: MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. when i try to submit the same thing you submitted in your example.

Comment: So i pasted that database object to the example you linked and it worked, so for some reason my code is not sending it there even though I have the same exact code. Strange. Error: `D:\Users\willi\Documents\Node\StudyWebApp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:106
      throw err;
      ^

MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.`

Comment: This is a node problem then, not mongo. But it seems that your DB in mongo hasn't a document with the match criteria. Have you inserted document with ```updateOne()``` or ```updateMany()```? It so, try first only a find query and check if any document is returned. Or even, try ```find({})``` to get all documents.

Comment: I have a find query that checks if the document has a submits array. So it does find the document and the array. I have narrowed down the problem to the $push query's "submits.$.subjects". It seems like the $ is not working correctly because when i removed it the error went away but the object got pushed to the wrong place. The problem is "submits.$.subjects".